# What is on my sink faucet? Trying to install RO system

Tags: plumbing, faucet, sink, kitchen-sink

I just moved into an apartment and I want to install a counter top RO system. These usually screw onto the faucet but the faucet in my apartment seems to have this plastic thing attached to it instead of any threading. What is this called? Can i install an RO system with it? If not, should/can I remove it(safely?), or try to get some kind of adapter? Is there an adapter for this even?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is just a cheap plastic aerator and should unscrew. Turn clockwise looking down on the faucet. There will probably be female  threads in the faucet. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a "washing machine adapter" or "dishwasher adapter" - same thing, really - a quick-connect fitting to allow use of an appliance via hose at full-bore flow.  Not the same as the one I use for my bottlewasher, but I'm sure there are multiple incompatible designs out there. Anyway, you can unscrew it and have the normal threads available.